# WPF Animation - Bring a Canvas to front

Tags: wpf, animation, canvas, wpf-controls, z-order

I have an animation that I have setup on a transparent `Canvas`.  I set that `Canvas` to be the content of a `Button` and then run the animation.  (See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909056/wpf-animation-dont-want-to-use-content) for the code.)

The problem is that sometimes the animation gets put behind other UI elements of my app (I am using Avalon Dock and it is in front of the `DockableContent` it is in, but behind the one next to it.)  In some tests this seems to be tied in some way to the size of the button (if it overflows the `DockableContent`).

Any idea how I can bring the `Canvas` to be on top of it all?   (Note: I am not trying to raise elements in the canvas over other elements in the `Canvas`.)

Thanks for any help.

---

**Edit:**
This was happening because I have a `ScrollViewer` around the button that was holding the animation `Canvas`.  This caused it to expand rather than overwrite.

I can think of a few workarounds, but I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the value of the [`Panel.ZIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex.aspx) attached property. A higher value means closer to the foreground

Comment: I cannot find Panel.ZIndex on the Canvas object.  (ie myCanvas.Panel.ZIndex is not a valid reference)

Comment: It is an *attached* property, you can't refer to it like that. You have to call it that way : `Panel.SetZIndex(myCanvas, 10)`. In XAML you can refer to it with `Panel.ZIndex`